# Degrees of freedom in Lie algebra structure constants

Tags: lie-algebras

[Disclosure:  As of 1/17/23, a [version of this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/438727/27465) has been posted on mathoverflow]

This may be a very naive question, but I'm having some trouble counting degrees of freedom for Lie algebraic structure constants.  Given an $n$-dimensional Lie algebra, there are $\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}$ degrees of freedom for the structure constants if one ignores the Jacobi identity.  Accounting only for very obvious symmetries, the Jacobi identity seems to impose $\frac{n^2(n-2)(n-1)}{6}$ constraints.  For $n>5$, there are far more of these than structure constants.  How does one reconcile this?  Of course, they are quadratic equations, not linear ones --- so it's not as simple as counting components.  But intuitively, it feels like the system is heavily over-constrained.  On the other hand, we know that solutions exist for $n>5$ (ex. $so(n)$).  It may be that I'm massively overcounting the Jacobi identity equations or am missing something obvious.  I'd appreciate any guidance on this.  In particular, if someone could point me to a more meaningful notion of "degrees of freedom" for the structure constants, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,
Ken

Comment: The situation is even worse in some sense, because structure constants related by a mere basis change correspond to isomorphic Lie Algebras --- so there even are fewer effective degrees of freedom.

Comment: Revisiting this:  My comment about basis changes is wrong since the structure constant eqs are basis independent.   Also, I'm moving this question to mathoverflow.